# Show multiple images in html, without writing a tag for every single one of them

Tags: html, image, automation

I am relatively new to html. I have 100 images in a folder. the first part of the images name are the same but the second parts are different. and example could be : "content_diffusion_delay_AthfT@jurEYTgf" and "content_diffusion_delay_BjgotYjho@jfbGoTR" and ...

Instead of using the tags  and  100 times, is there a way to tell the browser to show all images that their names start with "content_diffusion_delay_" ?

Comment: It's probably possible with jquery and partial selectors

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think there is a way around this in HTML, without writing the image tag individually and linking them to their source.

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP and need it as soon as possible. any suggestions?